# Disable touchpad in Linux Mint (or any similar distribution) permanently

Tags: linux, mouse, linux-mint, touchpad

My buggy touchpad in Linux Mint 20 keeps driving me crazy as it constantly turns of and on again after a few seconds though a mouse is connected. Maybe it is an issue with the mouse USB but as I hate touchpads anyways I simply want to force the touchpad to be always disabled. I tried various approaches like the tools `dconf-editor` and `touchpad-indicator` but despite of trying various settings it keeps torturing me (followed the guidelines here: https://vitux.com/how-to-automatically-disable-touchpad-when-mouse-is-connected-to-your-ubuntu-system/).

Is there any way in Linux Mint/Ubuntu to force my touchpad to not being activated (also after startup)? If I want to do something I connect a mouse, period.

Comment: Is disassembling your laptop not an option on the table? I have my Touchpad cable disconnected permanently from motherboard in my laptop. It is a one time tweak but it is going to last as long as you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

lsmod | grep touch

Note that hid_multitouch module … that is possibly what we are looking for.We need to ensure that we got the right module by looking into using modinfo

modinfo hid_multitouch | head

Seems legit, as the description clearly says it’s for HID multitouch panels.We could try to remove this hid_multitouch to see if that disables touchscreen.

modprobe -r hid_multitouch

Now this is still temporary. Next time I restart my laptop, it will load this hid_multitouch module again. To stop this Linux kernel module from auto loading, we need blacklist it. In Kali / Debian / Ubuntu, it’s as simple as creating a new blacklist file in modprobe.d folder with correct module name:

vi /etc/modprobe.d/hid_multitouch.conf

Save the file and reboot, hid_multitouch module will not be loaded next time. You can follow the same process to disable / unload Linux Kernel modules or blacklist Linux Kernel modules.